# Meaning of a c++ function parameter type declaration

Tags: c++

(I'm quite new to c++) In the line:

```
virtual void SetModifyHdl( const Link<Edit&,void>& rLink ) { maModifyHdl = rLink; }
```

what is the exact meaning of `Link<Edit&,void>&`?

It's in *libreoffice* code, https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/include/vcl/edit.hxx line 233.

Comment: 1) `Link` is the type, 2) `<Edit&,void>` is a template and 3) `&` is a reference.

Comment: Mmmmm, it's a type, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Link<Edit&,void>` is a specialization of a [templated class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) named `Link` taking 2 template parameters.  `Edit&` and `void` are the values of those template parameters.

This specialization is the type for the `rLink` parameter of `SetModifyHdl()`. The `&` means `rLink` takes a reference to an object instance of the above type. The `const` means the object being referenced can't be modified by `SetModifyHdl()`.